# SharePoint:CompositeField throws NullReferenceException during pre-render event

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I'm receiving this error on a custom SharePoint list form:
    Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Stack Trace: 

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.CompositeField.get_Visible() +41
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +22
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +223
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3393
```

The errors started occurring after I started using `<SharePoint:CompositeField>` in my form.  I may be wrong, but I'm attempting to use this control as I thought it would automatically adapt to the different field types of my various fields as well as adjusting to the page mode (new, edit, or display).  I suspect I'm using it incorrectly, but the MSDN documentation and any documentation I can find from surfing the web is rather sparse...

How should I use this control?  Or should I just break-down and manually deal with each individual field using basic asp.net controls?  Are there better options?  Amongst the couple dozen fields, a few need custom work - if not for them, the rest of the fields would be handled fine with SharePoint's default list item forms.

In my *.aspx page, under the `PlaceHolderMain` content element, I'm using the control like this:

```html
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<!-- more content -->
<div id="main-form">
    <!-- more content -->
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LTSAttachmentsLabel" AssociatedControlID="LTSAttachmentsCompositeField" Text="Attach File" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
        <SharePoint:CompositeField runat="server" ID="LTSAttachmentsCompositeField" FieldName="LTS Attach File" />
    </div>
    <!--
        about two dozen <div> tags; much of it similar to the above
        with Label and CompositeField controls
    -->
</div>
<!-- more content -->
</asp:Content>
```

I started with strictly declarative use, but after a series of errors and attempts to fix them, I'm now performing the following in my page PreInit and Load events:

```cs
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPreInit(e);
    _currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;  // page-scoped property
    string listGuid = Request.QueryString["List"];
    _formList = _currentWeb.Lists[new Guid(listGuid)];  // page-scoped property

    string itemGuid = Request.QueryString["Item"];
    if (!itemGuid.IsNullOrEmptyTrimmed())
    {
        _itemID = itemGuid.ToIntegerNullSafe();  // page-scoped property
        _item = _formList.GetItemById(_itemID.Value);  // page-scoped property
    }

    _pageMode = (SPControlMode)Enum.Parse(typeof(SPControlMode), Request.QueryString["ControlMode"]);  // page-scoped property
    if (SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode == SPControlMode.Invalid && _pageMode != SPControlMode.Invalid)
    {
        SPContext.Current.FormContext.FormMode = _pageMode;
    }

    if (Request.QueryString["IsDlg"] != null)
    {
        _formIsDialog = Request.QueryString["IsDlg"] == "1";  // page-scoped property
    }
    if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
    {
        _itemID = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ID"]);  // page-scoped property, unnecessary redundancy?
    }
}


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // unrelated code

    var spControls = from c in this.GetChildControlsRecursive()
                     where c is CompositeField
                     select c;

    foreach (CompositeField cf in spControls)
    {
        cf.ListId = _formList.ID;
        cf.ItemId = _itemID ?? -1;
    }

    // unrelated code

}
```

For the curious, `GetChildControlsRecursive` returns all child controls as a flat enumerable collection rather than a hierarchical collection.

```cs
// extension class in separate file
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Control> GetChildControlsRecursive(this Control parentControl)
    {
        Stack<Control> todo = new Stack<Control>();
        HashSet<Control> results = new HashSet<Control>();
        todo.Push(parentControl);
        results.Add(parentControl);
        while (todo.Count > 0)
        {
            Control parent = todo.Pop();
            foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
                if (results.Add(child))
                    todo.Push(child);
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially I dropped the whole idea of using the SharePoint:CompositeField and similar controls.  I went back to using basic ASP.Net controls.  Except for handling attachments, this worked fine.  But I couldn't figure out how to handle the attachments, but in my research for solutions I noticed that I might be able to resume using the default SharePoint list forms.  So that is what I tried, but then I ran into problems with the lookup fields.  I could not get them working with declarative XML, the fields had to be created during feature activation.  This in turn led to problems with the field sequence.  The lookup fields all appeared at the end of the form instead of their proper place amongst the rest of the fields.  I attempted to fix this by using the `FieldLinksCollection.Reorder(string[])` method, but this failed to update the list with the new field sequence.

Eventually, I used a combination of declarative XML to define my site columns, content types, list definitions, and list instances.  I then used the default list forms.  Though the lookup fields were present in the XML, they did not bind properly, I found some code suggesting a way to programmatically fix the broken binding: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18192756/1075980.  This combination of actions resolved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this applied to your situation, but it might help other googlers troubleshooting this error. I got the same error and found that the cause was that I accidentally snuck a `<SharePoint:CompositeField runat="server" />` into my form template below my `ListFieldIterator`. I believe the composite field belongs either in a field control or must have a property defined that tells it which field to render.